# Как из select сделать radio?

Tags: php, html

Есть форма с select которую надо перевести в radio button. При выборе одного из значений появляется поле для заполнения данными для этого поля.

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="uap-change-password-form">
 <div class="uap-ap-field">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("Тип", 'uap');?></label>
  <select class="uap-public-form-control" onChange="uapPType();" name="uap_type"><?php
   foreach ($data['p_types'] as $k=>$v):
    $selected = ($data['metas']['uap_type']==$k) ? 'selected' : '';
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $k;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $v;?></option>
    <?php
   endforeach;
  ?></select>
 </div>
 <div class="uap-ap-field" id="uap_with_email" style="display: none;">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("E-mail", 'uap');?></label>
  <input class="uap-public-form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['metas']['uap_email'];?>" name="uap_email" />
 </div>

 <div class="uap-ap-field" id="uap_with_nm" style="display: none;">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("Номер", 'uap');?></label>
  <textarea style="min-height: 100px;" class="uap-public-form-control" name="uap_data"><?php echo $data['metas']['uap_data'];?></textarea>
 </div>


 <div class="uap-change-password-field-wrap">
  <input type="submit" value="<?php _e("Сохранить", 'uap');?>" name="save_settings" class="button button-primary button-large" />
 </div>
 <?php if (!empty($data['error'])) : ?>
  <div><?php echo $data['error'];?></div>
 <?php elseif (!empty($data['success'])) : ?>
  <div><?php echo $data['success'];?></div>
 <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Надо сделать так чтобы при выборе одной из radio button появлялось поле для заполнения данных соответсвующих этой кнопке. Т.е., в принципе, оставить функционал этого скрипта, но с radio, а не select.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

UPD После советов ниже код выглядит так:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="uap-change-password-form">
 <div class="uap-ap-field">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("Тип", 'uap');?></label>
  <select class="uap-public-form-control" style="display: none;" onChange="uapPType();" name="uap_type"><?php
   foreach ($data['p_types'] as $k=>$v):
    $selected = ($data['metas']['uap_type']==$k) ? 'selected' : '';
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $k;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $v;?></option>
    <?php
   endforeach;
  ?></select>
 </div>
  
  <div class="radio-container">
      <div class="form-radio-btn">
      <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $data['metas']['uap_email'];?>" name="uap_email" id="radio1" checked>
      <label for="radio1">Email</label>
    </div>
      <div class="form-radio-btn">
      <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $data['metas']['uap_data'];?>" name="uap_data" id="radio2">
      <label for="radio2">Номер</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="uap-ap-field" id="uap_with_email" style="display: none;">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("E-mail", 'uap');?></label>
  <input class="uap-public-form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['metas']['uap_email'];?>" name="uap_email" />
 </div>

 <div class="uap-ap-field" id="uap_with_nm" style="display: none;">
  <label class="uap-ap-label"><?php _e("Номер", 'uap');?></label>
  <textarea style="min-height: 100px;" class="uap-public-form-control" name="uap_data"><?php echo $data['metas']['uap_data'];?></textarea>
 </div>


 <div class="uap-change-password-field-wrap">
  <input type="submit" value="<?php _e("Сохранить", 'uap');?>" name="save_settings" class="button button-primary button-large" />
 </div>
 <?php if (!empty($data['error'])) : ?>
  <div><?php echo $data['error'];?></div>
 <?php elseif (!empty($data['success'])) : ?>
  <div><?php echo $data['success'];?></div>
 <?php endif; ?>
</form>
<script>
$("radio").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})
 </script>
```

Но поле для каждой из кнопок не меняется. Показывается только для первой кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ставите display: none для select
2. Прописываете соответствующе radio
3. На js/jquery ставите на click в radio действие prevent default и display: block для соответствующего select.